# Does non-dimensionalizing ODEs affect the stiffness of the equations?

Tags: ode, stiffness

Does non-dimensionalizing ODEs affect the stiffness of the equations? Can it improve the stability of numerical methods like ode45,ode113 in MATLAB?

I am trying to solve 2 eqns. which might involve very tiny step size to get stability like 1e-11. I want to improve the speed of the numerical method. Can non dimensionalizing help in this regard?

The ODEs (I.V: Rbar, N) are shown in link [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxiDt.png). The output should be close to that shown in [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfO2N.png)

My **working code** for a test problem:

```
clc
clear
close all
tic

T  = 273 + 160 ;  
Xo = 0.06;

[SS,delGv,rc,Z,rstar,delGstar,I_nu] = nucleate2(Xo, T, 0);

t  = [1 1e7];
y0 = [rstar,1];
options = odeset('InitialStep',1e-3,'MaxStep',100);
[t1,y1] = ode23(@(t,y)NOCmodel2(t,y,T),t,y0,options);

figure(1)
set(gcf, 'Position',  [100, 100, 900, 800])
loglog(t1,y1(:,1),'-b');
xlabel ('time(s)')
ylabel ('$R_{mean}$','Interpreter','latex')
set(findall(gcf,'-property','FontSize'),'FontSize',20,'fontweight','bold')


figure(2)
set(gcf, 'Position',  [100, 100, 900, 800])
loglog(t1,y1(:,2),'-r');

xlabel ('time(s)')
ylabel ('$logN (/mm^3)$','Interpreter','latex')
set(findall(gcf,'-property','FontSize'),'FontSize',20,'fontweight','bold')

figure(3)
set(gcf, 'Position',  [100, 100, 900, 800])
semilogx(t1,y1(:,2),'-r');
xlabel ('time(s)')
ylabel ('$N (/mm^3)$','Interpreter','latex')
set(findall(gcf,'-property','FontSize'),'FontSize',20,'fontweight','bold')

toc

function [yprime] = NOCmodel2(t,y,T)
Rm = y(1);
N  = y(2);

%A. Known variables
Xp         = 1; 
Xo         = 0.06; 
R          = 8.314 ;                             %Gas constant
kB         = 1.38064852 * 1e-23 ;                %R/avogadro no.
Na         = 6.02214 * 1e23;                     %avogadro no.
IncXe      = 0.01;                               %Equilibrium mol frac.
sigma      = 0.13;                               %interfacial free energy J/m2
Di         = 5e-20;                              %aDiffusivity
Vinc       = 1.6*1e-29*Na;                       %m3/mol
VFe        = Vinc;                               %Vinc;


%B. Calculated properties

alpha      = VFe/Vinc;
Rzero      = 2*sigma*Vinc/R/T;
IncXieq(1) = IncXe ;
IncXi(1)   = IncXieq(1)*exp(2*sigma*Vinc/(R*Rm*T));

if Rm <0
   error('negative Rm') 
elseif N < 0
   error('negative N') 
end

% Solute balance
X_O = (Xo - alpha*(4/3)*pi*Rm^3*N*Xp)/(1 - (alpha*(4/3)*pi*Rm^3*N*Xp));


%C. number density
[~,~,Rstar,~,Rcrit,~,C1] = nucleate2(X_O, T, t) ;

f_coars = 0 ;
if Rm < 1.01*Rstar && Rm > 0.99*Rstar
    f_coars = 1-(1000*((Rm/Rstar) - 1)^2) ;
end

D1 = (4/27) * ((IncXieq(1))/(alpha*Xp - IncXieq(1))) * (Rzero*Di/Rm^3) * ((((Rzero*IncXieq(1))/(Rm*(Xp - IncXieq(1)))) * ((3/(4*pi*Rm^3))) - N) - 3*N);

dNdt = abs(min(0,(C1+D1)/abs(C1+D1)))*f_coars*D1 + max(0,(C1+D1)/abs(C1+D1))*C1;


%D. mean radius
A1 = (Di/Rm)*((X_O - IncXi(1))/(alpha*Xp - IncXi(1))); A2 = (1/N)*dNdt*(Rcrit - Rm);

A = A1 + A2 ;
B = (4/27) * ((IncXieq(1))/(alpha*Xp - IncXieq(1))) * ((Rzero)*Di/Rm^2) ;

%fprintf('t = %1.1e, A1 =  %2.2e, A2 =  %2.2e, B =  %2.2e, C =  %2.2e, D =  %2.2e, fc = %2.2f, Rm = %2.2e, dNdt = %2.2e, xo = %2.2e, N = %2.2e, Rcrit = %2.2e\n',t,A1,A2,B,C1,D1,f_coars,Rm, dNdt, X_O,N,Rcrit )

yprime = [f_coars*B + (1-f_coars)*A ; abs(min(0,(C1+D1)/abs(C1+D1)))*f_coars*D1 + max(0,(C1+D1)/abs(C1+D1))* C1];


end

function [SS,delGv,rc,Z,rstar,delGstar,I_nucl] = nucleate2(Xo, T, t)
R         = 8.314 ;                             %Gas constant
kB        = 1.38064852 * 1e-23 ;                %R/avogadro no.
Na        = 6.02214 * 1e23;                     %avogadro no.
IncXe     = 0.01;                               %Equilibrium mol frac.
sigma     = 0.13;                               %interfacial free energy J/m2
Di        = 5e-20;                              %aDiffusivity
Vinc      = 1.6*1e-29*Na;
VFe       = Vinc;                               %Vinc;
a         = 4.04e-10 ;                          %lattice parameter FCC iron 


Vm1       =  Vinc;                              %m3/mol  
Vm        =  Vm1/Na;                            %m3
SS        =  Xo/IncXe;                          %reaction quotient of bulk steel
delGv     = -R*T*log(SS)/Vm1;                   %chemical driving force (J/m3)                                                                   
rc        = -2*sigma/delGv ;                    %critical radius (m)
Z         =  Vm/(2*pi*rc^2)*sqrt(sigma/kB/T);   %Zeldovich factor
rstar     =  rc + 0.5*sqrt(kB*T/(pi*sigma)) ;   %(1/(Z*sqrt(pi))); %m
delGstar  =  16*pi*(sigma)^3/(3*delGv^2) ;      % J



betastar  = 4*pi*rc^2*Di*Xo/a^4;
tow       = 0.5/(betastar*Z); 

PreEx     = betastar * Z * Na/VFe;
I_nucl    = PreEx * exp(-delGstar/kB/T) * exp(-tow/t);



end
```

}

Comment: If you could add the equations to your question, you might get an answer that's more informative then "It all depends on the details of your problem."

Comment: In theory it should not, but in practice the solvers make heuristical decisions generalizing the behavior of test cases. So if the non-dimensionalizing moves your system towards these test cases, which it should if done sensibly, then the behavior of the solver can improve, which might look like stiffness was reduced.

Comment: Hi, I have added the eqns for refernce. @LutzLehmann, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: It looks like $N'$ has a jump discontinuity in its ODE. How do you treat this? Branching in the ODE is sub-optimal, it is better to have two smooth ODE systems and use an event mechanism to switch.

Comment: I actually do it by:
abs(min(0,(C1+D1)/abs(C1+D1)))*f_coars*D1 + max(0,(C1+D1)/abs(C1+D1))*C1 where C1,D1 are the dN/dt for the 2 types.

Comment: Yes, that produces a jump. The solver "sees" the jump as a region of stiff behavior and thus reduces the step size. If you enter a sliding mode, then this persists for some time. If you manage the switch externally, this disappears. If you are careful, you can get a similar improvement by mollifying the jump into some continuous function with a steep slope. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60309851, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54767096 for examples

Comment: Also, if your problem is stiff, you should use specialised integrators such as ode15s, ode23tb in Matlab. These are implicit methods which will take more computational time per time step, but will be able to take much larger time steps and overall may be much more performant. Note that this is actually one of the first definition of stiffness given by Curtiss & Hirschfelder in 1952: "stiff equations are equations where certain implicit methods [...] perform tremendously better than explicit ones".

Comment: And regarding the effect of non-dimensionalisation, it should not affect the stiffness of the system. I think it can be explained with the following linear system: $\dot{x}= Ax$, a non-dimensionalisation of $x$ could be $\tilde{x} = Bx$ with a constant invertible $B$, therefore the original system is equivalent to $B^{-1} \dot{\tilde{x}} = A B^{-1} \tilde{x} $, i.e $\dot{\tilde{x}} = B A B^{-1} \tilde{x}$. The eigenvalues of $BAB^{-1}$ will be the same as those of $A$, therefore the stiffness arising from the disparity of the eigenvalues (e.g. fast and slow variables) will be preserved.

Comment: Hi, @LutzLehmann,  I understand that an event function (function [value,isterminal,direction] = myEventsFcn(t,y)) can be used, but I do not know what values to give to "value", "isterminal", and "direction". Also, while I say this, my MATLAB program does run for a simple test case but when I try it on my actual problem (substitute the parameters), I end up having some results in the beginning and then,enters into an infinite loop.

Comment: `value` contains the test conditions, that is, if the phase change is at $h_1(x)==h_2(x)$, then `value=h_1(x)-h_2(x)` (or an array of such conditions). `isterminal` determines an action, the only action available, to terminate the integration for this event. Else the event just gets registered in the returned arrays. `direction` provides a filter, if the event should only be triggered when the region $h(x)>0$ is left, but not when it is entered, then `direction=-1`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66354995/solve-system-of-differential-equation-in-python for a very artificial example that should be solvable as it is, but figuring out appropriate tolerances could be bothersome. The appropriately transformed system however can run with default tolerances.

Comment: @Laurent90, I have tried other solvers in MATLAB too but I receive the same problem.

Comment: @LutzLehmann, are you suggesting to scale N, R by a factor to get the solver to perform better within default tolerances?

Comment: I do not follow at once how this influences the formulas, but that you have constants `1e-23, 1e-19, 1e+23` involved opens the possibilities that the components will have different scales. I believe to remember that the numerical machine of Mathematica will analyse this correctly without changes, perhaps Maple too. But already Matlab is not CAS enough that you could rely on that. Python-scipy does not even raise the topic. So yes, it could make a marked difference in the obtainable precision if you rescale the variables.